# return format yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss(String) to java Date

Tags: java, android

I have a function that needs to return a Date, I have a Date String of

```
    '2016-02-09T12:22:00.000+00:00'
```

and want to convert it to

```
    '2016-02-09 12:22:00'
```

but my return result is a string, in my case i want this to be a date. Here is my function so far i have tried is:

```
    private Date parse(String s){ // function needs to return date as yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
       SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
       Date d = null;
       try {
           d = sdf.parse(s);
       } catch (ParseException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       String formattedTime = output.format(d);
       System.out.println("Formated Date is = "+ formattedTime); // return date in yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss (but a string)
       return date; (Here i want the expected date to be as yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss, I am getting as 'Tue Feb 09 12:22:00 GMT+05:30 2016')
    }
```

Please help me its been a while trying this and am failing every time.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure ,is the variable date defined and you are using it?

Comment: A Date has no format.

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Date has no any format, it's just... date. `yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss` is string representation according to some format (your code has this), `'Tue Feb 09 12:22:00 GMT+05:30 2016'` is result of default `toString()`.

Just parse string into Date object and return it, then call `SimpleDateFormat.format(date)` wherever it needs to be showed / logged / whatever.